# Xcode 6.0.1 не запускает ios симулятор

Tags: xcode

Начинающий разработчик )) Видимо так совпало, что на момент скачивания была версия именно 6.0.1.
Сборка проходит успешно, а симулятор висит черным окном. Можно ли как-то установить старую версию xcode, где нет таких проблем?

Answer (score 1):

В настройках проверьте вкладку `download`, возможно, симулятор не скачан или его надо обновить.

Answer (score 0):

Да просто версии должны совпадать (симулятора и Xcode)